# Silverlight, WCF service relay and security

Tags: wcf, silverlight, web-services

I have a silverlight 4 application which needs to consumes some services hosted on a Java (I think CXF) Web Service.
For some reasons, I can't access directly the service so I have to go through a relay service.
I created a WCF relay service.
The service uses SOAP 1.2 and WS addressing 1.0

What I ask is.. what level of security can I reach?
The ideal situation is to use a mutual authentication of the server (CXF) and my client.
If Silverlight does not support this, the second possibility is to have a "simple" https connection between my silverlight client and my relay server, but then, is it possible to "add" a mutual authentication between the relay and CXF? Or the only possible solution is to have a simple SSL connection with only the server authentication?